# How to enable and disable p tag in react when certain condition passes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How to enable and disable p tag in react when certain condition passes.
On button click I called a function validate inside this there is comparison if its success then only p tag should be visible 
after p tag is visible then Validate button should be disabled.

I tried this logic but it fails

Should we use eval?

```
export default function practice() {

    const [validation, setValidation] = useState("");
    const [result, setResult] = useState(0);
    const [inputValue, setInput] = useState("");

    const [sucessfull, setSucessfull] = useState({ "text": "You have Successfully Subscribed", "disabled": "true" })
    const [failed, setFailed] = useState({ "text": "Wrong Captcha", "disabled": "true" })

    const Generators = () => {
        const data1 = Math.round(10 * Math.random());
        const data2 = Math.round(10 * Math.random());
        const alpha = ['+', '-', '*'];
        const a = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
        const str = ` ${data1} ${a} ${data2} `
        const res = eval(`${data1} ${a} ${data2}`)
        setValidation(str);
        setResult(res)
    }

    const handleInput = (e) => {
        setInput(e.target.value)
        console.log(inputValue)
    }

    const validate = () => {
        const x = result.toString();
        const y = inputValue.toString();
        setInput("");
        if (x === y) {
                alert("success")
                setSucessfull(sucessfull.disabled = true)
            }
        else {
            alert("fail");
            setFailed(sucessfull.disabled = true)
            Generators();
        }
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <h3 >{validation}</h3>
            <input id="input-Number" type="text" onChange={e => handleInput(e)} value={inputValue}></input>
            <button onClick={Generators}>Refersh Captcha</button>
            <button onClick={validate} >Validate</button>
            <div>
                <p disabled = {sucessfull.disabled}>{sucessfull.text}</p>
                <p disabled ={failed.disabled}>{failed.text}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are checking is it is successfull might not be the best. This could be better, give it a try. Remove failed state as you only should need one state to manage this, keep the succesfull one and initialize it to null. Then I do not really get what a disabled p is ( I think you mean the text you want to show ). Then show a text or another bassed on succesfull state:

```
export default function practice() {

  const [validation, setValidation] = useState("");
  const [result, setResult] = useState(0);
  const [inputValue, setInput] = useState("");

  const [sucessfull, setSucessfull] = useState(null);

  const Generators = () => {
      const data1 = Math.round(10 * Math.random());
      const data2 = Math.round(10 * Math.random());
      const alpha = ['+', '-', '*'];
      const a = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
      const str = ` ${data1} ${a} ${data2} `
      const res = eval(`${data1} ${a} ${data2}`)
      setValidation(str);
      setResult(res)
  }

  const handleInput = (e) => {
      setInput(e.target.value)
      console.log(inputValue)
  }

  const validate = () => {
      const x = result.toString();
      const y = inputValue.toString();
      setInput("");

      alert(x === y ? "success" : "fail")
      setSucessfull(x === y)
  }


  return (
      <div>
          <h3 >{validation}</h3>
          <input id="input-Number" type="text" onChange={e => handleInput(e)} value={inputValue}></input>
          <button onClick={Generators}>Refersh Captcha</button>
          <button disabled={sucessfull} onClick={validate} >Validate</button>
          <div>
              { succesfull !== null &&
                  <p>{sucessfull ? 'You have Successfully Subscribed' : 'Wrong Captcha'}</p>
               }
          </div>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Carlos Saiz Orteu  its working fine can you tell how to resolve compilation of eval ```eval(`${data1} ${a} ${data2}`)```

Comment: Is that a string concat or what do you want the result to be?

Comment: for example let  number generated be( data1 = 7 and data2 = 8 a = +) then ```const res = eval(`${data1} ${a} ${data2}`)`` provide result be 15

Comment: actually + sing is generated randomly

Comment: I been searching and testing on js console and your code seems to be ok. Does it throw any error? Else what is the result it gives you?

Comment: Everything is fine I know  just read that we should never use eval

Comment: Oh, yeah I know but generally you won't need to go for math operations where all components of it are strings so I do not really know how you could avoid it in that case. Sorry mate!

Answer (score 0):

Note: [`p` tag does not have a `disabled` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p#Attributes), it is reserved for [form control elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled).

---

It appears you're attempting to do the following:

- Only render the `p` tag after `validate` is run.
- Render the success or failure text.

Your two variables `sucessfull` and `failed` can be combined into a single state variable:

```js
const [valid, setValid] = useState(null)
```

Update `valid` with `setValid` to `true` or `false` within `validate` and the following render logic will work:

```
{valid !== null && <p>{valid ? 'You have Successfully Subscribed' : 'Wrong Captcha'}</p>}
```

Comment: I do get your point but  @Carlos Saiz Orteu  already answer my problem . Thanks to you to. can you help me @Jacob in resolving this error how to resolve compilation of eval ```eval(`${data1} ${a} ${data2}`)```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?
What is the output you're expecting?

I believe you can remove the `eval()` statement and just run ` ${data1} ${a} ${data2} `